# Is there SOQL function to convert Date to Unix timestamp in Salesforce SOQL or SOSL?

Tags: salesforce, unix-timestamp, soql

Hi Salesforce developers,

I am exporting standard Contact fields with **Salesforce SOQL**. I need to import it to other tool but I need to convert **LastModifiedDate**, which is ISO datetime string, into **Unix timestamp seconds** from 1/1/1970.

```
SELECT Email,LastModifiedDate FROM Contact

    Email                           LastModifiedDate
1   john.doe@trailhead.com          2020-10-27T14:06:12.000Z
2   laetitia.arevik@trailhead.com   2020-10-27T14:06:11.000Z
```

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

I am using iPaaS platform to load SOQL via API (app.tray.io, elastic.io and [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) for debugging issues) so I don't have access to write custom javascript or apex code.

I checked the official [Salesforce Date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm), but I don't see a function that I need.

**Not** working:

```
SELECT Email,FirstName,LastModifiedDate.getTime(),LastName FROM Contact
SELECT Email,FirstName,DateTime(LastModifiedDate).getTime(),LastName FROM Contact
```

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make a new formula field (type = number) with something like `(LastModifiedDate - DATETIMEVALUE('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) * 24 * 60 * 60`. And `SELECT LastModifiedTimestamp__c...` or however you'd call it.

I don't remember if it does seconds or milliseconds, you might have to multiply by 1000.
Bit wasteful to have a field just for that but well, what you can do.